# Can I get the DOS for command to substitute the file owner and creation times?

Tags: for-loop, cmd, dos

I am running the following command in cmd.exe to list files recursively...

```
for /r %i in (*) do @echo %~xi %~zi %~ti %~fi
```

.. to get output like this:

```
.ext 187392 15/01/2014 14:16 C:\path\to\filename\f.ext
```

But can I get the file owner added to this output? I'm looking for the same owner that `dir /q` gives me. I'd also like to get the file creation time rather than the last-access time which I believe `%~ti` is giving me.

If I can't do this using for, is there a way I can do it using a combination of `for` and `dir`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

< lang-dos -->

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
for /r "%sourcedir%" %%i in (*.pdf) do (
 SET "grab="
 FOR /f "skip=5tokens=1,2,4delims=\ " %%a IN ('dir /q /tc /-c "%%~fi"') DO IF NOT DEFINED grab (
  SET grab=Y
  echo %%~xi %%~zi %%a %%b %%c %%~fi
 )
)
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. I used a filemask of `*.pdf` to make the test results more legible. You want different? Change it!

Comment: That only gives me the domain of the user, not the full *domain\username* string

Comment: Ah- eliminate the `\` from the `delims string. Use simply a space.